# Qt Virtual Keyboard in Raspberry pi with multi language

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, qml, cross-compiling

I want to use Qt Virtual Keyboard in my QML application on Raspberry pi. 
I use `qtrpi` [link](https://github.com/neuronalmotion/qtrpi) for cross-compiling my code.

I install qtrpi and the Virtual Keyboard module and run sample app on my rpi correctly, but my problem is the default language is English, and I can't add more languages to it.

I read this [link](https://forum.qt.io/topic/76802/how-to-enable-virtual-keyboard-languages/5), which stated that I should recompile the virtual keyboard module with `qmake "CONFIG+=lang-all"` argument. (I use "qmake-qtrpi" instead of `qmake` because I'm cross-compiling, though.)

I do this on my laptop (not on rpi) and run the sample app again, but it doesn't work. How can I solve this?

**Edit:** All code is in this [repository](https://github.com/qt/qtvirtualkeyboard).

Comment: Sorry but have you tried with `qmake-qtrpi "CONFIG+=lang-all"`?

Comment: yes i run this command in this path of my laptop "/opt/qtrpi/modules/qtvirtualkeyboard"

Comment: I know this post is too old, but do you get the answer?

Comment: yes, read this link  https://github.com/neuronalmotion/qtrpi/issues/74